# How to send datas from an Angular form to Spring Boot microservice

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to send the values of username and password from a form in Angular to a REST controller in Spring Boot, this is my html form:

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input required ngModel name="loginUsername" #loginUsername="ngModel" type="text" placeholder="Username">
  <div class="notValid" role="alert" *ngIf="loginUsername.invalid && (loginUsername.dirty || loginUsername.touched)">
    Username not inserted
  </div>
  <input required ngModel name="loginPassword" #loginPassword="ngModel" type="text" placeholder="Password">
  <div class="notValid" role="alert" *ngIf="loginPassword.invalid && (loginPassword.dirty || loginPassword.touched)">
    Password not inserted
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

This is the little that I have written in the REST controller:

```js
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@RequestMapping
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class ApiGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The dependencies that I have in the controller are:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.5.4'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:3.0.4'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway:3.0.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.5.4'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:3.0.3'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.5.4'
}
```

What do I have to add in such a way that I can be able to retrieve the values and use it in the controller? The Angular page is on localhost:4200 and the REST controller is on localhost:9090. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. What you are calling your rest controller is basically just the main class for a Spring application. Just slapping a RestController annotation on there doesn't make it a rest controller. You want to create some separate class with that annotation on it and then add methods to handle requests. In your case annotated with PostMapping and taking an object that maps to your form data.
On the front-end side you want to make a post request using HttpClient to the endpoint of your rest controller.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the most basic example I can give you.

Simple rest controller example:

```java
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public User postUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        System.out.println("User firstname:" + user.getFirstname());
        return user;
    }
}
```

*If this class is in the same directory as your main application class in your Spring project (or in any subdirectory) it will be automatically picked up if you have the spring-boot-starter-web artifact in your .pom or .gradle file.*

Your front-end service:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TodoBoardService {
  readonly API = environment.apiUrl + 'login/'

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  postUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post<TodoBoard>(this.API, user)
  }
}
```

*In your component you would use this service to make a post request using the object created by your form.*

*Both of these snippets assume some definition in your code of what a User is. That being said, creating a login service is probably not the easiest place to start.*

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer.
I have understood the first part of the code that you have posted but I still don't get the passages that I have to do to pass the datas from the form to the REST controller